# Jenkins and chef continuos integration

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox, chef-infra, virtualization

On a Jenkins Master-Slave configuration and need to run on the slaves Kitchen tests on several jobs, Kitchen for those who doesn't know it, runs infrastructure on demand using Vagrant and Virtualbox (in my case). Master and slave are both under Proxmox, so my questions is: is there a sane way to get running Virtualbox inside an OpenVZ container?, is there any workaround I can do to achieve this? I just don't want to create a physical node to run this kind of jobs, Any help is appreciated, Thanks in the advanced

Comment: What about using vagrant with openvz and not Virtualbox? https://github.com/abrooke/vagrant-openvz

Comment: Yep, you should make that the answer, Draco, I'll +1 it.  It does seem a bit odd to want to run a virtual machine inside your virtual machine.

Comment: Draco, post this as an answer so I can accept it